# Direct product of integral extensions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $S_1, \ldots ,S_n$ be integral ring extensions of $R$. Thus, for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ all elements $s_i \in S_i$ are integral over $R$. The direct product $S_1 \times \cdots \times S_n$ is the ring of $n$-tuples $(s_1, \ldots, s_n) \in S_1 \times \cdots \times S_n$ endowed with componentwise addition and multiplication

$$(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n)(s_1^{\prime}, s_2^{\prime}, \ldots, s_n^{\prime}) = (s_1s_1^{\prime}, s_2s_2^{\prime},\ldots, s_ns_n^{\prime}),$$

$$(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n) + (s_1^{\prime}, s_2^{\prime}, \ldots, s_n^{\prime}) =(s_1 + s_1^{\prime}, s_2 + s_2^{\prime},\ldots, s_n + s_n^{\prime}).$$

> I would like to show that $S_1 \times \cdots \times S_n$ is an integral ring extension of $R$ just by using the definition of integrality.

More precisely, I have to prove that there exists a monic polynomial $g(x) = x^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1x + c_0 \in R[X]$ such that $g(s_i) = 0$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Does anybody has an idea how to show this ?

> Moreover, is this also true if there are infinitely many integral ring extensions $S_i$ of $R$ ?

Comment: Short hint: by induction, you can immediately reduce to the case $n = 2$. It doesn't make solving the problem any easier (the solution is quite easy, as can be seen by the answer by Arthur below), but you don't have to write all the dots anymore. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for each $i \leq n$, $f_i$ is a monic polynomial such that $f_i(s_i) = 0$, then consider the product $g = f_1\cdot f_2\cdots f_n$.

Answer (score 1):

For an infinite family it may not be true, like for instance 
$R=\mathbb{Z}$, and $S_n = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: At the moment I do not really understand your counterexample. Can you please give me a more detailed explanation ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ is an overshoot. Even $S_n=\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$ will do. Since $(1,2,3, \ldots, )$ does not satisfy any integral equation over $\mathbb{Z}$ ( the hypothetical polynomial would have to be divisible by all $(X-n)$, for all $n \ge 1$.